# SvelteKit: How to refer to the /routes folder from components and endpoints via alias, like $routes?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

The next is my (simplified) project structure:

```
appname
|
|__src
|  |__lib
|  |__routes
|
|__jsconfig.json
```

In the jsconfig.js file, I have paths key with an alias to a './src/lib' folder in form of $lib.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "$lib": ["src/lib"],
            "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"]
}
```

I want to access routes folder with $routes alias in the same way as $lib.
But if I add "$routes": `["src/routes"]` in above JSON file, sveltekit cannot resolve the path starting with `'$routes/somefile'`

Example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "$lib": ["src/lib"],
            "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
            "$routes": ["src/routes"],
            "$routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"]
}
```

endpoint.js

```
import { db } from '$routes/db';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also have to tell the bundler to use it in *svelte.config.js*

```js
kit: {
  vite: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        $routes: path.resolve('./src/routes')
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

That said, remember that **all files** in the routes folder except for the ones starting with an _ underscore) are considered to be routes. So if you have file `/src/routes/db.js` a user can go to `http://yoursite.domain/db`.

There is very rarely any reason to import a file from there and if you need to do so, it likely is not a route or endpoint and can be safely put in `lib` instead

**Update 31.01.2023**

The above answer was written *before* a major overhaul of how routes work in SvelteKit. Nowadays routing is directory based and only the file `+page.svelte` will actually create a route (so `/src/routes/about/+page.svelte` will give you the `/about` route). This means that you can safely add other files and components to the route folder.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's VS code's file structure confused me. There is a small indentation and it seemed that my hooks.js, db.js, and other files are under routes, but they are under the src folder.
But anyway, now I need to access the $src folder. And when I add $src: path.resolve('./src') it says that path is not defined. What is the path variable in here? Do I need to import it?

Comment: yes, you have to import path: `import path from 'path';` should do

Answer (score 7):

**Oct 2022:** The official documentation for [Alias](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias) makes it clear:

```
// @svelte.config.js

kit: {
  adapter: adapter(),
  alias: {
    '$routes': './src/routes',
    '$routes/*': './src/routes/*',
  },
}
```

- No need to modify `tsconfig.json`
- Make sure you run `npm run dev` after making the changes

Comment: This is the better answer at this time, and can be simplified to just `alias: {$routes: 'src/routes'},`.

If you're wondering why you'd want this, absolute paths are easier to change and search (and usually read IMO). VSCode and the Svelte language tools are pretty good at updating import paths automatically when you rename files, so it's less important to avoid breaking imports, but there's enough cases where I dislike relative paths that I sought this out.

Answer (score 0):

To complement on [Stephane Vanraes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71481472/9888500) answer.

I'm using SvelteKit with TypeScript so I add the path to `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```json
{
  "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "$routes": ["src/routes"],
      "$routes/*": ["src/routes/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then I setup `svelte.config.js` as follows:

```js
import path from 'path';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    vite:{
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          $routes: path.resolve('./src/routes'),
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
```

If you are also using Vitest, you can setup export the object
provided under `config.kit.vite` and import it in your `vite.config.ts`
file as follows:

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

import { viteConfig } from './svelte.config.js';

import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  ...(viteConfig as UserConfig),
  plugins: [svelte()],
});
```

This way you can import routes for testing from your Vitest suites.