# How to pass object through anchor to next page?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a page at `routes/+page.svelte` with this on it:

```html
{#each foos as foo}
  <a href="/foo/{foo.id}">{foo.id}</a>
{/each}
```

Then at `routes/foo/[id]/+page.server.ts` I am taking that `id` and reloading the entire `foo` from the database.

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async({params}) => {
  const foo = await db.foos.findFirst({where: { ID: params.id }});

return { foo };
```

As you can see it's pretty inefficient to re-grab the `foo` from the database when the page before this already had the full `foo` object from the `{#each foos as foo}` that was surrounding the anchor tag.

So, is there a better way to pass the entire object from the anchor before this and re-use it on the subsequent page? I've tried modifying the `$page` store but not sure if that is the right way, or how exactly to do it through that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a store that store the values inside it and import it in both your pages :

```
// routes/_store.js
export const foos = writable([]);
```

Then you load your objects client side (in the onMount for example) :

```
// routes/+page.svelte
import {foos} from "./store.js"

onMount(async () => {
    const foosResult = await // load from server;
    foos.set(foosResult);
});
```

Then in `routes/foo/[id]/+page.svelte` you can have :

```
// routes/foo/[id]/+page.svelte
// You may want to use alias for cleaner imports : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71481056/sveltekit-how-to-refer-to-the-routes-folder-from-components-and-endpoints-via
import {foos} from "../../_store.js"

let foo;
onMount(async () => {
    foo = $foos.find(foo => x.id == params.id);
    // May want to handle foo == null if the user navigate directly to the page
    if (!foo)
        // load from server
});
```